# Bearer token is not set in call to backend via Axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

We are switching our authentication service from a custom implementation with cookies to an approach with refresh tokens by Auth0. The Auth0 react package provides us with a `getAccessTokenSilently` function which we use in an `Interceptor` context provider and add the token to our `Axios` client via an interceptor.

The structure of the different parts looks like this:

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Auth0Provider
            domain={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
            clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
            redirectUri={window.location.origin}
            audience={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE}
        >
            <BrowserRouter>
                <NotificationProvider>
                    <Interceptor>
                        <NotificationList />
                        <Router />
                    </Interceptor>
                </NotificationProvider>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Auth0Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**apiClient.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    timeout: 10000,
});

export default apiClient;
```

**Interceptor.js**

```
const Interceptor = ({ children }) => {
    const { addNotification } = useContext(NotificationContext);
    const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const getAccessToken = async () => {
            try {
                const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
                console.log('TOKEN: ', token);
                setAccessToken(token);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        getAccessToken();
    }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

    useMemo(() => {
        apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
                config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
                return config;
            },
            (error) => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            },
        );

        apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => {
                return response;
            },
            (error) => {
                if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
                    if (error?.response?.status === 504) {
                        addNotification('error', 'Oops!', 'gateway_timeout');
                    } else {
                        addNotification('error', 'Oops!', 'server_down');
                    }
                } else {
                    addNotification('error', error.response?.data?.title || 'Oops!', error.response?.data?.description);
                }

                return Promise.reject(error);
            },
        );
    }, [accessToken]);

    return <>{children}</>;
};

export default Interceptor;
```

**profileService.js**

```
import apiClient from '../utils/apiClient';

export default {
    getProfileInfo() {
        return apiClient.get(`/profile`);
    },
    updateProfile(data) {
        return apiClient.put('/profile', data);
    },
};
```

We use different service files to separate our calls to the backend by topic and centralize them away from our user interface.

We are expecting that our access token would be added as Bearer token to our calls to the API but this is not the case. If we check the headers from our call we get `Authorization: Bearer undefined` while if we console.log the access token in the Interceptor provider we get an access token.

How can we set the token correctly via an interceptor?

**EDIT 1: Extra code to show where the profileService functions are being used**

**Router.js**

This is a part of the router.js file.  in App.js is executing this code

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
    return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : loginWithRedirect();
};

const Router = () => {
    const { isLoading } = useAuth0();

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Spinner />;
    }

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route element={<GuestRoute />}>
                <Route element={<GuestLayout />}>
                    <Route path='/account/verify' element={<VerifyAccount />} />
                </Route>
            </Route>

            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
                <Route element={<OnboardingLayout />}>
                    <Route path='/onboarding' element={<Onboarding />} />
                </Route>

                <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='/profile' replace />} />
                    <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
                </Route>
            </Route>

            <Route path='404' element={<NotFound />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/404' replace />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

**Profile page**

Part of the profile page where the call to profileService.getProfileInfo is being called.

```
const ProfileOverview = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getProfileInfo();
    }, []);

    const getProfileInfo = async () => {
        const { data } = await profileService.getProfileInfo();
        reset({ ...data });
    };

    const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        watch,
        reset,
        getValues,
        formState: { errors, isDirty },
    } = useForm({
        resolver: useYupResolver(editProfileValidationSchema),
    });
```

Comment: Where and how are you actually using `getProfileInfo` and `updateProfile`?

Comment: `getProfileInfo` is being called from the profile page. `updateProfile` is used in the onboarding flow and later on the profile page

Comment: Can you post some code for it?  You've coupled the client to the react lifecycle of the code you posted, so you're not at liberty to use it without coupling those profile pages to this.  Given no other information it's entirely possible you're trying to use it before it's initialized.

Comment: @possum I have added the `router.js` and `profileOverview.js` code under 'EDIT 1'. In router.js there is a loading spinner while auth0's `isLoading` property is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Interceptor />` component is setting the axios's interceptor with an actual `accessToken` on the "second" render caused by calling the `setAccessToken()` in the effect. (on the first render, your `accessToken` is `undefined`)

And because you are making your `apiClient.get()` request only on the first render of your `<ProfileOverview />`, the latter was probably already mounted when the "second" render of your `<Interceptor />` was triggered, resulting in your axios's interceptor not being updated with the accessToken yet.

**EDIT possible solution:**

Convert your `<Interceptor />` component to a **Provider** exposing in a context if the token was set:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

export const InterceptorContext = createContext({ isTokenSet: false });

const Interceptor = ({ children }) => {
    
    // ...

    return (
        <InterceptorContext.Provider value={{ isTokenSet: !!accessToken }}>
            {children}
        </InterceptorContext.Provider>;
};

export default Interceptor;
```

and in your `<ProtectedRoutes />` component check if the token is set before rendering the `<Outlet />`:

```
import { InterceptorContext } from '....';

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
    const { isTokenSet } = useContext(InterceptorContext);
    return isAuthenticated && isTokenSet ? <Outlet /> : loginWithRedirect();
};
```

Comment: Any suggestion on how we can make the api calls wait till the token is set?

Comment: Since you need the token only on **Protected Routes**, I would modify the `<Interceptor />` Component to a `Provider` exposing in a context if the token was received and set. And check in your `<ProtectedRoutes />` component if the token is set before rendering the `<Outlet />`, this way you know that all subcomponents of your protected routes wich are making fetch request will have the token present in the headers

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply interceptors as soon as possible after the creation of `apiClient`. If the `apiClient` interceptor needs `<Auth0Provider/>` in order to provide `accessToken`, I would call `<Interceptor/>` right after.

```
<Auth0Provider
  domain={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN}. 
  clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
  redirectUri={window.location.origin}
  audience={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE}
>
  <NotificationProvider>
    <Interceptor>
      <NotificationList />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Router />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Interceptor>
  </NotificationProvider>
</Auth0Provider>
```